# I want to make an arrow that the base width is half of the size of the input

Tags: php, shapes

I have this code that works but is missing some details

```
$input=7;
$k=($input+1)/2;
        for($i=1;$i<=$input;$i++){
            for($j=1;$j<=$input;$j++){
                if($j==($input+1)/2 || $j==$k || $j==$input-$k+1){
                    echo "*";
                }
                else{
                    echo "-";
                }
            }
            echo "<br>";
            $k++;
        }
```

And the output look like this

```
---*---
--***--
-*-*-*-
*--*--*
---*---
---*---
---*---
```

My desired output is

```
___*___
__***__
_*****_
*******
__***__
__***__
__***__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer guys, thank you all.

```
    $x=($input/2); $y=$x+1; $w=($input/2);
    if($w%2==0) {
    $w++;
    }
    for($i=1; $i<=$input; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j<=$input; $j++) {
    if($j>=$x && $j<=$y) {
      echo "*";
    }
    else {
      echo "_";
    }
}
if($i>(($input-1)/2)) {
  $x=(($input-$w)/2)+1;
  $y=($x+$w)-1;
}
else {
  $x--;
  $y++;
}
echo "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you have three conditions. So there can only be three stars in a row.

I think your structure is more complex as it should be. You could use `str_repeat` instead. Something like this:

```
$input=7;

for($i=1;$i<=$input;$i+=2) {
    echo str_repeat('-', ($input - $i) / 2 ) .
      str_repeat('*', $i) .
      str_repeat('-', ($input - $i) / 2 ) .
      '<br>';
}

$shaft = floor($input / 2);

for($i=1;$i<$input/2;$i++) {
     echo str_repeat('-', ($input - $shaft) / 2 ) .
       str_repeat('*', $shaft) .
       str_repeat('-', ($input - $shaft) / 2 ) .
       '<br>';
}
```

The first loop draws the triangle which is growing by 2 each row.

The second loop draws the shaft.

Comment: I'm sorry but I should not use ```str_repeat``` so I just type for loop and if else

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to do it only using loops and if else, you have to elaborate your if statement. Here's my solution:

```
$input = 7;

for($i=1;$i<=2*$input;$i+=2) {
    for($k=1;$k<=$input;$k++) {
        if(($i <= $input && $k > floor(($input - $i)/2) && $k <= ceil(($input + $i)/2)) ||
            ($i > $input && $k > ceil($input/4) && $k <= floor(3/4*$input))) {
                echo "*";
        } else {
                echo "-";
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Note: In the first loop I use `$i+=2`, so with every iteration `$i` increases by two. To get the right number of lines the loop continues till `2*$input`.

The `if` statement has two parts. In the first part the triangle is drawn (adding two stars every row since `$i` increases by 2). In the second part, when `$i` becomes greater than `$input`, drawing the shaft, which is half the width and 1/4 of the width on each side.